# If a firestore query task failed (task.isSuccessful() returns false), can I expect task.getException() to return a non null value

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore in my android application.

In following code, can I expect the exception to be non null?

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("items").document("abc").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Exception e = task.getException();
        //Can I expect e to be non null, or do I have to check for null?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an OnCompleteListener, you are guaranteed to have either a result or an exception.  If `task.isSuccessful()`, you are guaranteed to have a result object and no exception.

```
addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        // Exception is guaranteed to be non-null
        Exception e = task.getException();
    }
    else {
        // Result is guaranteed to be non-null
        task.getResult();
    }
});
```

If you use an `OnSuccessListener`, the result is guaranteed to be non-null, but will not get invoked if there is an error.

If you use an `OnFailureListener`, the exception is guaranteed to be non-null, but it will not get invoked if there is no error.

You can chain an `OnSuccessListener` and a `OnFailureListener` if you don't want to check for success inside a `OnCompleteListener`.

You can read my canonical reference for Tasks in [this blog series](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).

Answer (score 1):

By the docs of task in OnComplete method, yes it must be not null.

Returns the exception that caused the Task to fail. Returns null if the Task is not yet complete, or completed successfully. link - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getException()